# Why aren't my CTreeCtrl checkboxes checking?

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

I've got a MFC CTreeCtrl stuck in a dialog with the TVS_CHECKBOXES style turned on. I get checkboxes next to all my tree items fine. In OnInitDialog I set the checked state of some of the items using CTreeCtrl::SetCheck but none of the items in the tree are checked when the tree is displayed. SetCheck is returning TRUE. Checking items with the mouse works fine. Anyone encounter this before?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Figured out what the problems was. I was setting the TVS_CHECKBOXES style in the visual studio resource editor. Apparently this causes the problem I was having with the initial checks. Instead you have to do

```
   m_nodeTree.ModifyStyle (TVS_CHECKBOXES, 0);
   m_nodeTree.ModifyStyle (0, TVS_CHECKBOXES);
```

before filling the tree in OnInitDialog. Once I did this everything worked fine.

Comment: This seems like such a silly answer, but it perfectly solved my issue as well :)  For the record, using VS2008 here...

Comment: Nice one - just ran into this bug myself.  For me, the problem only occurs if I don't specify an image list.

Comment: This is called out in [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760013%28v=vs.85%29.aspx): "If you want to use this style, you must set the TVS_CHECKBOXES style with SetWindowLong after you create the treeview control, and before you populate the tree. Otherwise, the checkboxes might appear unchecked, depending on timing issues." (You're working too hard, turning the style off and back on. Just turn it on once, in code. Don't turn it on in the resource editor.)

Answer (score 2):

I created myTreeCtrl using this code:

```
myTreeCtrl.Create(WS_CHILD|TVS_HASBUTTONS|TVS_CHECKBOX|, CtrlRect, this, IDC_TREECTRL);
```

I tried to check some items in `OnInitialDialog()` and had the same problems.
I tried:

```
myTreeCtrl.ModifyStyle(TVS_CHECKBOXES, 0);
myTreeCtrl.ModifyStyle(0, TVS_CHECKBOXES);
```

And now it works fine.

More than that, it didn't check the item if it was not in the visible part of the window. I had to put a trigger on `OnVScroll()`.

Answer (score 1):

Check boxes in tree view controls are quirky. As [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760013.aspx):

> If you want to use this style, you must set the TVS_CHECKBOXES style with [**SetWindowLong**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633591.aspx) **after you create the treeview control**, and before you populate the tree. Otherwise, the checkboxes might appear unchecked, depending on timing issues.

In other words, you cannot set the `TVS_CHECKBOXES` tree view style at control creation time. Control styles set in Visual Studio's resource editor (which is just a graphical front-end for the .rc script) are used at control creation time.

The solution is fairly simple: Create the control without the `TVS_CHECKBOXES` style, and turn it on in code, before you populate the control:

```
::SetWindowLong( hwndTreeView, GWL_STYLE,
                 ::GetWindowLong( hwndTreeView, GWL_STYLE ) | TVS_CHECKBOXES );
```

In MFC this can be done using

```
m_treeView.ModifyStyle( 0x0, TVS_CHECKBOXES );
```

where `m_treeView` is the tree view control instance variable.

---

### Background information:

Check boxes weren't part of the initial tree view control implementation. They were added later on, following the scheme developers were using that needed check boxes before they were available: By using a state image list and setting state item indices on the tree view items.

One of the issues that needed to be addressed was determining the check box size. If the tree view control has an image list (the "normal image list") assigned, the check boxes should match the size of those images. Otherwise, the check boxes should use the system small icon size. A corollary of this is that if you are using a "normal image list", you need to enable the `TVS_CHECKBOXES` style **after** setting the image list.

Another quirk is, that the state image index `0` means "no state image" at all (`1` refers to the "unchecked" state item image). If you add an item to a tree view control that has the `TVS_CHECKBOXES` style set, the control sets the state item index to `1` (even if you specify `0`). That's why all items appear unchecked, when you set the `TVS_CHECKBOXES` style at creation time. This also implies, that if you want a tree view item without a state image, you have to add the tree view item, and then manually reset the state item index.

This should be enough information, to understand and solve the question as asked. There's a lot more to the tree view implementation, but I'll leave that to someone, that is better equipped to write about it. Refer to the *references* below.

---

### References:

Raymond Chen ([The Old New Thing](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/)) has published an extensive series covering the tree view control quirks. Not all of the entries are immediately relevant to this question, but each and every one is insightful and valuable, one way or another, so I'll just list them all:

- [The TVS_CHECKBOXES style is quirky, which is a polite way of saying that it is crazy](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20171127-00/?p=97465)
- [Beware of the leaked image list when using the TVS_CHECKBOXES style](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20171128-00/?p=97475)
- [Creating tree view check boxes manually: A simple state image list](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20171129-00/?p=97485)
- [Creating tree view check boxes manually: Responding to clicks](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20171130-00/?p=97495)
- [Creating tree view check boxes manually: Themed check boxes](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20171201-00/?p=97505)
- [Tree view check boxes: A sordid history](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20171204-00/?p=97515)
- [Tree view check boxes: The extended check box states](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20171205-00/?p=97525)